# How can I read a file and split each line in C++?

Tags: c++, file, loops, split

I have a file like this:

4 88 101

1 22 100

6 41 151

I have 3 arrays and i want to put the first values(4, 1, 6) to my first array, the second values(88, 22, 41) to my second array etc.
So how can I split each line by space??

I have already read the file but I cannot fill my arrays with these values.

Comment: The third elements can be integer.

Comment: I know in my code i have 3 integer.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, check the section with the `getline`. After that you can use boost::split to split the line you obtained http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact number of items per line of data from the file, you can open it with an `ifstream` and do:

```
int firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum;

while (inFile >> firstNum >> secondNum >> thirdNum)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me, but i try it again...